# Why scsi_id not found in my Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line

Why `scsi_id` not found in my Ubuntu?

```
$ scsi_id
scsi_id: command not found
```

No `You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install package` prompt is provided.

using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Tried with `sudo`? It's in the `/sbin` directory usually.

Comment: @muru, `sudo` also does not work. It's not located in `/sbin`.

Comment: Looks like a bug then.

Comment: in comparision on RedHat5.3  https://superuser.com/questions/1246322/how-to-get-the-scsi-identifier-by-scsi-id-command

Answer (score 2):

`scsi_id` is in `/lib/udev`.

So either write the whole path as

```
/lib/udev/scsi_id
```

or append `/lib/udev` to the PATH variable and export the path.

```
/lib/udev/scsi_id <OPTIONS>
```

or

```
PATH=$PATH:/lib/udev
export PATH
scsi_id <OPTIONS>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install it :)
Ubuntu

```
apt-get install udev
```

Other OS related installs if someone required.

Alpine

```
apk add udev
```

Kali Linux

```
apt-get install udev
```

CentOS

```
yum install udev
```

Raspbian

```
apt-get install udev
```

Docker

```
docker run cmd.cat/scsi_id scsi_id
```